# Kotlin + Gson - How to get an emptyList when null for data class

Tags: kotlin, gson

Lets to say I have the following data class:

```
data class MyDataClass(@SerializedName("myList") val myList: List<String>)
```

And I try to parse this JSON:

```
{ "myList": null } or {}
```

I want to get an empty list but I get a null `myList`. Does anyone know how to serialize this without implementing a `registerTypeAdapter` for each type containing a list?

If I set `emptyList()` as default value for the constructor. The second JSON works as I want to.

Comment: It's theoretically possible whatever library/framework you use uses reflection, and therefore bypasses the constructor, and sets the values directly.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but I would find a way to set null list as empty by default

Comment: Without a `TypeAdapter`, I cannot think of any way. Maybe something with `Gson.Builder.serializeNulls`. You should try anyway with a `TypeAdapter` first IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Switch your `@SerializedName("myList") val myList: List<String>` to:

`@SerializedName("myList") val myList: List<String>?` just to be safe from `null`.

Now, Kotlin has default parameters. But I don't know if it fits your case:

```
data class MyDataClass(@SerializedName("myList") val myList: List<String> = emptyList())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with kotlinx.serialization